# Generate admin pages for MVC SqlRoleManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, role-manager

I want to add admin MVC pages for maintaining users and roles for users for the SqlRoleManager.  Is there a template or generator available or do I need to build it from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at my project [Ilaro.Admin](https://github.com/rgonek/Ilaro.Admin). These is still a alpha version but with simple stuff like a roles and users managing should work very well.